# pg_restore terminates with "out of memory" error

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Trying to restore a 45mb pg_dump file but it keeps failing with an "out of memory" error.

Content of my postgresql-10-main.log:

```
2018-01-16 06:14:50.692 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development LOG:  

could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-01-16 06:14:50.692 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development CONTEXT:  COPY assessment_scores, line 15347
2018-01-16 06:14:50.692 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development STATEMENT:  COPY assessment_scores (id, student_id, assessment_id, score, exempt, late, collected, missing, comment, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;

2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development LOG:  incomplete message from client
2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development CONTEXT:  COPY assessment_scores, line 15347
2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development STATEMENT:  COPY assessment_scores (id, student_id, assessment_id, score, exempt, late, collected, missing, comment, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;

2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development ERROR:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development CONTEXT:  COPY assessment_scores, line 15347
2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development STATEMENT:  COPY assessment_scores (id, student_id, assessment_id, score, exempt, late, collected, missing, comment, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;

2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost
2018-01-16 06:14:50.693 WAT [32405] postgres@app_development LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
```

I checked with HTOP, my RAM is at about 4GB/8GB and SWAP space is unused when this happens.

DB server is localhost.

Comment: I think the issue should be `FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost`. It's not related to `out of memory`.

Comment: Please show the options you are giving to pg_restore.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem.

I was trying to import a DB dump from Postgres 9.6 to Postgres 10.

Downgraded to Postgres 9.6 and it imported successfully.

Comment: Umm - if that's truly the case you should report a bug to postgres against that exact version of 10: using pg_dump and pg_restore is the recommended way to upgrade to a new major version of postgres (ie, it *should* have worked).

Answer (score 0):

As there is no mention of 'out of memory' in the server side logs, and apparently your client (`pg_restore` in this case) dies, I'd bet the OOM happens on your local machine.  Solving this might depend on many factors - try to close processes that consume a lot of RAM, add more swap, or other.

Comment: I checked with HTOP, my RAM is at about 4GB/8GB and SWAP space is unused when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue while trying to restore some dumps, **in `-Fc` custom format**. I'm not sure the problem will or can occur with any of the other dump formats.

However, I found that the "*out of memory*" error that `pg_restore` laconically drops on exit, is program-internal and not actually an OOM. It also occured without any DB interaction, when 'restoring' the dump into another dump using the `pg_restore -f output.sql input.dump` form.

Unlike in your instance, it didn't help to use an older pg_restore or an older database and I found that the (very big, 200-400+GB uncompressed) dumps were simply corrupt in some places, due to a badly aging disk I used for the storage.
Since I didn't use the `-Fc` internal compression, but bzip2 on the whole dump, I could recover pretty much everything but the few records inside broken bz2 segments (something not possible with xz or other container formats, thanks bzip).

**Recovery** requires some knowledge about `pg_dump`'s custom dump format. In my instance the errors all occured in the data segment of the dump which was a `COPY` statement. Without internal compression this looks just like the plain-sql COPY format, including newline-delimiters after each row. Though the custom format additionally prepends each line by a 4-byte integer (little-endian here) containing the line-length in bytes and a 0x00, then ends it with another 0x00.
I expect the "out of memory" error occurs when the line-length indicated by the int doesn't fit the broken row's length, and `pg_restore` doesn't find the terminating NULL it expects but reads into the next row.

But due to the newline from `COPY` preceding the NULL on every line, I could actually open the dumps in a pager like less, and use `head` and `tail` to exclude the broken rows and stitch the rest back together for a restore.

Using the earlier mentioned `pg_restore -f output.sql input.dump` form, I dumped the backup until the error, then would tail this output to get the last good / first broken row, using that row's data as a regex to `csplit` the original dump, drop the last row from the first segment, the first row from the second segment, and stitch the rest together again.
That final command then looked something like:
`cat <(head -n -1 dump.xx00) <(tail -n +2 dump.xx01) | pg_restore -C -d postgres`.

I hope this might help someone else with broken dumps. I conclude that using `-Fc` custom format isn't in some cases the best thing to use (recovery using plain SQL format would have been much simpler), and that `pg_restore` could really use some better error reporting.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using the below without tweaking any buffer size and it worked.

```
psql -U <db_user_name> -d <db_name> -f <file_name>.sql
```